# Custom return type declarations

Tags: c++

I was hoping someone could help me with a little issue I'm having trouble understanding in c++.

If I create a private enum within a class in a header file (Example.h) as shown below:

```
class Example
{
    private:
        enum ValueType
        {
           INTEGER,
           BOOLEAN,
           BLOB,
           UNKNOWN
        };
}
```

Then how can I access these values from a source file (private method) to be used as a return type (Example.cpp)

```
#include "Example.h"

...

ValueType // <-- How can I declare this correctly? compiler complains
Example::returnMyType(const ValueType p_valueType)
{
    switch(p_valueType)
    {
        case INTEGER;
        return "INTEGER";  
        break;
   ...
   ...
}
```

I'm just unsure how to declare this as the return type.

Also I know this function is pointless but it's only for putting across the concept I'm trying to understand.

I was also wondering how could I access these values from within the switch statment?

```
#include "Example.h"

...

ValueType // <-- How can I declare this correctly? compiler complains
Example::returnMyType(const ValueType p_valueType)
{
    switch(p_valueType)
    {
        case Example::BLOB; // <-- Is this how to access 
        return "INTEGER";  
        break;
   ...
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write that as:

```
Example::ValueType Example::returnMyType(const ValueType p_valueType)
{
     //...
}
```

That is, you've to use `Example::ValueType` from outside the class, when defining members functions and from the member functions.

--

From your comment:

> I see, it the enum were public would this also be the case?

Yes. It doesn't matter if it is `public` or `private`.

Accessibility (*public*, *protected* and *private*) only determines **who** is allowed to access, it doesn't determine **how** to access.

Comment: I see, it the enum were public would this also be the case?

Comment: @aliaserror: Yes. It doesn't matter if it is public or private. `public` or `private` only determines **who** is allowed to access, it doesn't determine **how** to access.